# Angular ui route stateparam in substate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some issues with using a stateparam in a substate.

This is my 'master' state

```
.state("shop", {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/shop/:nameSlug',
    templateUrl: '/views/shop/index.html',
    controller: 'shopController',
    params: {
        nameSlug: null,
        }
    })
```

And this is my substate:

```
.state('shop.payment-success', {
    url: '/payment-success?transactionid',
    templateUrl: '/views/payment-success.html',
    controller: 'checkoutController'
})
```

I want to use the param 'transactionid' in my controller, but when I log it, it's undefined.

I have tried with $stateParams and $state.params, but there is no difference between them.

Is there a way to make transactionid available in 'checkoutController'?

For your information: the param ?transactionId is coming from a payment gateway and I can't change it. It contains the orderId, what I have been needed for a check for a genuine payment.

Comment: Hi, did you forget the : before the variable transactionid ?

Comment: @PortePoisse also have tried that, no results..

Comment: I think you need both the url variable and the declared params (as @Valter said) because angular filters the url...

Answer (score 0):

try this: [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls)

```
.state('shop.payment-success', {
    url: '/payment-success',
    params: {
          transactionid: null
    }  
    templateUrl: '/views/payment-success.html',
    controller: 'checkoutController'
})
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still undefined in `console.log($state.params);` and `console.log($stateParams)`