# Angular UI Router remove slash in ? parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Currently I have this issue: [Angular ui route stateparam in substate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254388/angular-ui-route-stateparam-in-substate/42254721)

After some tries with route params and other methods in the url of the state like `{transactionid}` and `[transactionid]` I noticed that there is an / added before the ? of the parameter. So, the URL look liks:

```
website.com/page/?transactionid=someid
```

but, I think it must be

```
website.com/page?transactionid=someid
```

We currently remove the trailing slash of any url using this code

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);

$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.path();
    var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

    if(hasTrailingSlash) {
        //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
        var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
        return newPath; 
    }
});
```

But, how can I remove the '/' before an 'question' mark?

The route for 'payment-success' (see question in link) currently looks like:

```
.state('shop.payment-success', {
    url: '/payment-success{transactionid}',
    templateUrl: '/views/payment-success.html',
    params: {
        transactionid: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        transactionid: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams);
            return $stateParams.transactionid
        }]
    }
```

Comment: sorry but why don't you use instead something lke: .state('shop.payment-success', {
    url: '/payment-success/:transactionid',
    templateUrl: '/views/payment-success.html',
    params: {
        transactionid: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        transactionid: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams);
            return $stateParams.transactionid
        }]
    }

Comment: because the parameter ?transactionid is returned from a payment gateway and I can't change it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the standard routing (you have more options and it's more easy..and don't have to remove nothing).. something like:

```
.state('shop.payment-success', {
    url: '/payment-success/:value/:squash', //<-- HERE YOU SET THE PARAM .. YOU CAN HAVE MORE THAN ONE
    templateUrl: '/views/payment-success.html',

    resolve: {
        transactionid: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams);
            return {value:$stateParams.value,squash:stateParams.squash}
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, change it, but the console.log in resolve, still returns 'transactionid: null'

Comment: That works if the url is like `website.com/payment-success/value/squash` but the url is like `/payment-success?transactionid=someid`